Is it idiomatic to say "home to diverse population"?

My city is home to diverse population

I meant to use this phrase when speaking, not writing. And I wonder if it sounds a little bit literary.
So is it idiomatic to say this?

As soon as you are planning your speech, it is no longer "spoken English".


My city is home to diverse population

As you are using the singular population, you need an article:

My city is home to a diverse population.

Such a construction with home to a diverse population is fine both in speech and in writing.
Examples of usages of diverse population(s) are shown below:

Auckland has such a diverse population and this really shows in the food.


And they all encompassed large territories, with diverse populations.


But why lump together all the diverse populations that happen to share similar skin pigmentation?


I suppose wildlife is "uncountable" rather than singular or plural. But it's the only word I can think of that sounds okay with or without the article in home to [a] diverse wildlife.

@FumbleFingers, Ludwig has an example for diverse wildlife used in this sense with the indefinite article: This, in turn, is expected to create a habitat for a diverse wildlife, and restoring the migratory bird patterns and ecological heritage which have been recently lost in Madurai.  The other two examples it said are exact matches are in fact not as the phrase is used as an attributive noun.
When we search for usage without the diverse, we get no return.

I didn't realize exactly how it worked before, but looking at your example I'm in no doubt it's better to include the article in that cited "habitat" context. Similar to A chastened John apologized to his mother metaphorically implying the existence of other "non-chastened" Johns, your one with article more strongly implies the possible existence of other "non-diverse" wildlife (where this particular habitat specifically homes and suits the diverse kind).

@FumbleFingers I think the "home to" setup makes it even more inflexible. For example, I could imagine both "This area has seen heavy influx of caribou" and "a heavy influx of caribou," but not "home to a heavy influx of caribou" (even if "home to" made sense with "influx").

@AndyBonner: I can't say I like article-less has seen heavy influx... - which finds no "viewable" instances at all in Google Books, whereas there are at least a few pages for the same text with a before heavy influx. But without getting bogged down in whether the article is "required" there, I don't think it has the same implication as my a chastened John..., which I think is a consideration with habitat for [a] diverse wildlife (other habitats may host a non-diverse wildlife).
